# Linking a software construct to a relational table's row value

Tags: sql, database, data-structures

### TL;DR

What's the preferred method of linking a programming object, such as a variable, to a row in a lookup table?

It seems like the best way is to hard-code the lookup table's PKs in some data structure in the software (like an Enum) and use that. Is that what most people do or is there another solution that I'm missing?

### What the heck does he mean by that?

Assume you have two tables:

[image: Example tables. See below for DDL]

and some software that uses them:

```python
class Param(Enum):
    stress = 1              # param_name = "Stress (kPa)"
    bow = 2                 # param_name = "Bow (um)"
    unknown = 3             # param_name = "unknown"

def add_main_table_item(param, data):
    if param == "stress":
        param_id = Param.stress
    elif param == "bow":
        param_id = Param.bow
    else:
        param_id = Param.unknown

    # INSERT INTO `data` (`parameter_id`, `value`) VALUES (2, 3.14159);
    magic_insert_function(param_id, data)
```

My question pertains to those hard-coded PK values `1`, `2`, and `3` in the enum. Is that the best way to go?

### Potential solutions:

Below are the couple idea I have bouncing around my head to solve this issue. The problem is that I can't seem to decide on one to use.

#### Option 1: Use an Enum, like in the example

This makes programming nice, but it has a few flaws:

1. If the string representation `param_name` changes, then the Enum becomes un-linked to the table, causing confusion
2. If another row is added to the `parameter` table, then the Enum, and thus the program needs to be updated.

We could extend this by making a dynamically-generated enum, which basically pulls the entire `parameter` table into it on creation, but this has issues such as

1. making strings programming-friendly (replacing spaces, removing special chars, etc) makes it harder to say that Enum "bow_center" links to the row `Bow Center`
2. A change in representation means code changes.

#### Option 2: Add a `software_name` column

We can add a column to the `parameter` table which is what software should use when referencing a row. This column would need to be Unique.

Flaws:

1. This is effectively adding another PK column
2. The `software_name` column would have to be non-descriptive, or else it would eventually be disjoint with the `param_name`.

#### Option 3: Looking up the string value

Instead of hard-coding the PK value, we can look it up each time we need to use it. For example:

```python
def add_main_table_item(param, data):
    # SELECT `parameter_id` FROM `parameter` WHERE `param_name` = 'bow'
    param_id = magic_select_function(param)

    # INSERT INTO `data` (`parameter_id`, `value`) VALUES (2, 3.14159);
    magic_insert_function(param_id, data)
```

This basically shifts the link from the PK to the string representation. This has similar disadvantages:

1. If the string representation `param_name` changes, code needs to change.
2. Doubles the number of queries executed (assuming no caching)

### Reference: SQL to create the tables

```mysql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`parameter` (
  `parameter_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `param_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parameter_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `param_name_UNIQUE` (`param_name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`data` (
  `data_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parameter_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_id`),
  INDEX `data_parameter_id_idx` (`parameter_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `main_table_lookup_table_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parameter_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`parameter` (`parameter_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```